# Delete records from database older than 1 hour doesn't delete all records

Tags: mysql

I have simple script which should delete all orders older than 1 hour and not provide string. The problem is that order which are older than 1 hour BUT are made today ( current date ) are not deleted. It's delete all records from yesterday. This is my query

```
$select = "DELETE FROM orders              
           WHERE created_at < DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 HOUR ) 
           AND tx = ''";

$conn->exec($select);
```

`created_at` is in `timestamp` and looks like `2016-10-06 08:33:14`.

I have order which is `created_at` - `2016-10-06 08:33:14` and current date and time is `2016-10-06 12:10:23` which isn't deleted but if I change date of this order to `2016-10-05 12:10:23` i.e. yesterday it's deleted.

What can be the problem here?

Comment: are you sure tx is '' and not NULL?

Comment: ever tried to do a `select * from orders WHERE created_at < DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 HOUR ) AND tx = ''`?

Comment: `select * from orders WHERE created_at < DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 HOUR ) AND tx = ''"` return 0 rows

Comment: `select * from orders WHERE created_at < DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 HOUR ) AND tx IS NULL` return also 0 rows

Comment: whit `tx = ''` I mean when there is nothing in this column i.e. empty. But the column isn't defined as NULL if user doesn't enter anything. It's just empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `curdate()` only returns date but not time:  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_curdate.asp

i.e. you are actually deleting orders which is older than `23:00` of yesterday

Change to use `NOW()` instead of `CURDATE()` may help.

Comment: Ah, you're correct. With `NOW()` today's records are deleted.